# Sprint Data JPA - save() methods inserting duplicates in table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a **Downtime entity**.  I am setting values to downtime object and passing these object into **JpaReposirtory** `save(downtimeobject)` method. `save()` inserting duplicate records. I gone through forums but  no luck, I didn't get any solution. Right now I am doing after saving object into database, checking whether duplicates are inserted or not. If inserted, I am removing through **JpaRepository** `delete(downtimeId)`.

My downitme entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tDownTime")
public class DownTime {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DowntimeId")
    private int downtimeId;

    @Column(name = "SiteId")
    private int siteId;

    @Column(name = "PlantId")
    private int plantId;

    @Column(name = "UnitId")
    private int unitId;

    @Column(name = "EquipmentId")
    private int equipmentId;

    @Column(name = "ShiftId")
    private int shiftId;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeReasonId")
    private Integer downTimeReasonId;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeReasonName")
    private String downTimeReasonName;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeReasonDescription")
    private String downTimeReasonDescription;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeStartDate")
    private LocalDate downTimeStartDate;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeStartTime")
    private LocalTime downTimeStartTime;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeEndDate")
    private LocalDate downTimeEndDate;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeEndTime")
    private LocalTime downTimeEndTime;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeDuration")
    private Long downTimeDuration;

    @Column(name = "HourResetTime")
    private LocalDateTime hourResetTime;

    @Column(name = "KPIDate")
    private LocalDate kPIDate;

    @Column(name = "CreatedBy")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "CreatedOn")
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @Column(name = "ModifiedBy")
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "ModifiedOn")
    private LocalDateTime modifiedOn;

    @Column(name = "SKUId")
    private int sKUID;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeStartDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime downTimeStartDateTime;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeEndDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime downTimeEndDateTime;

    @Column(name = "WorkOrderId")
    private int workOrderId;

    @Column(name = "IsManual")
    private boolean isManual;

    @Column(name = "AutoPauseResume")
    private boolean isAutoPauseResume;

    @Column(name = "DowntimeType")
    private String downtimeType;

    @Column(name = "DownTimeStatus")
    private String downtimeStatus;

DownTime downTime = new DownTime();// creating object for setting values to object to save as entity

downTime.setUnitId(calculationOEEHelper.getUnitId());   downTime.setEquipmentId(calculationOEEHelper.getEquipmentId());
downTime.setShiftId(calculationOEEHelper.getShiftId());
downTime.setDownTimeReasonId(0);
downTime.setDownTimeReasonName(ParameterTags.UNASSIGNED);
.
.
.

downTime = downtimeRepository.save(downTime);
```

it is inserting 2 entires in database. I am using MSSQL DB

> DownTime [downtimeId=2148, siteId=1, plantId=1, unitId=12,
>   equipmentId=33, shiftId=28, downTimeReasonId=0,
>   downTimeReasonName=Unassigned, downTimeReasonDescription=Unassigned,
>   downTimeStartDate=2019-05-11, downTimeStartTime=06:36:42,
>   downTimeEndDate=2019-05-11, downTimeEndTime=06:37:23,
>   downTimeDuration=41, hourResetTime=2019-05-11T07:30:01,
>   kPIDate=2019-05-11, createdBy=SYSTEM,
>   createdOn=2019-05-12T01:06:55.865, modifiedBy=SYSTEM,
>   modifiedOn=2019-05-12T01:06:55.865, sKUID=5,
>   downTimeStartDateTime=2019-05-11T06:36:42,
>   downTimeEndDateTime=2019-05-11T06:37:23, workOrderId=74,
>   isManual=false, isAutoPauseResume=true,downtimeType=NOT SCHEDULED,
>   downtimeStatus=Running]
>
> DownTime [downtimeId=2149, siteId=1, plantId=1, unitId=12,
>   equipmentId=33, shiftId=28, downTimeReasonId=0,
>   downTimeReasonName=Unassigned, downTimeReasonDescription=Unassigned,
>   downTimeStartDate=2019-05-11, downTimeStartTime=06:36:42,
>   downTimeEndDate=2019-05-11, downTimeEndTime=06:37:23,
>   downTimeDuration=41, hourResetTime=2019-05-11T07:30:01,
>   kPIDate=2019-05-11, createdBy=SYSTEM,
>   createdOn=2019-05-12T01:06:55.865, modifiedBy=SYSTEM,
>   modifiedOn=2019-05-12T01:06:55.865, sKUID=5,
>   downTimeStartDateTime=2019-05-11T06:36:42,
>   downTimeEndDateTime=2019-05-11T06:37:23, workOrderId=74,
>   isManual=false, isAutoPauseResume=true,downtimeType=NOT SCHEDULED,
>   downtimeStatus=Running]

downtimeId is different, remaining all are same

can some body help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share some more logs or add some logger before the save/persist method? Looking at entity and persist method it’s hard to tell what’s happening behind the scene.

Comment: Your objects have different I'd, they are not duplicates.

Comment: Those are not Java Objects. I copied here DB Records

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve, but this seems like expected behavior. If you want to update object instead of creating new, you should fetch old version from the repository and set values on it.

Comment: What I Posted here is those are DB records. not Java Objects.

Comment: You posted an entity class which represent's DB table, i assume that you're using some ORM like Hibernate (which in simple words maps your database rows into java objects).

Now, when you use `downtimeRepository.save(downTime);`, your application inserts new row in table `tDownTime` because u created new entity instead of updating old one.

To update old entity, you should first fetch it from the repository (try `downtimeRepository.findAll()`, `downtimeRepository.findOne(<id>)`), then update the data using setters, and finally save your changes using `downtimeRepository.save(<entity>)`.

Comment: You can read about it more [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring)